# Como faço para deixar meus objetos em JS estático?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vou explicar o que tá acontecendo,

bem quando eu crio uma aplicação com vuejs ou react, eu uso o fetch para recuperar informação da api e depois passo os dados dentro de uma state (no caso do vuejs eu uso `return { info: [] }`)

Quando eu chamo esse objeto coloco para exibir dentro do HTML, aí as informações aparecem mas quando dou F5 elas dão refresh...

Alguém sabe alguma solução para tirar o refresh quando atualizar a página?

Comment: Queres evitar fazer uma chamada de novo à API correto? A tua aplicação tem algum servidor?

Comment: Estou trabalhando localmente, não estou usando servidor ainda.

Comment: E isso não acontece apenas com API, eu também já usei o firebase e acontece a mesma coisa

Answer (score 0):

Você pode persistir os dados em storage, quando inicar a aplicação você carrega os dados salvos. Isto é para memória do navegador, tipo um cookie. Se quiser persistir definitivo você deve salvar as alterações na API para resgatá-las ao carregar a aplicação. Um pequeno exemplo se armazenagem no Storage:

```
// Gravar
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Recuperar
variavel = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```